# Inferring the conservation of angular momentum from linear momentum

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, momentum, noethers-theorem, integrals-of-motion

Working in 3-dimensions, if we are given a Lagrangian containing $N$ particles.  Say, through Noether's theorem, we know that the sum of the linear momentum of all $N$ particles in each direction are constant.  We also know that the sum of the angular momentum in each direction are constant.

My question is, if I know that linear momentum is conserved, can I actually automatically say that angular momentum is also conserved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Linear monemtum conserved with in angular momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292068/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. Consider the two-particle Lagrangian
$$L = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{\vec{x}}_1^2+\dot{\vec{x}}_2^2) - \vec{a}\cdot(\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1)$$
for some arbitrary vector $\vec{a}$. This is fully translation invariant, and so Noether's theorem implies that momentum is conserved. However, it is not invariant under rotations because of the preferred direction $\vec{a}$, so angular momentum is not conserved.

Note that this Lagrangian is symmetric under rotations around $\vec{a}$ so it does conserve the angular momentum around that axis. We can make it conserve no components of angular momentum by adding another term like $(\vec{b}\cdot(\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1))^2$ where $\vec{b}$ is not parallel to $\vec{a}$.